# 500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined WHILE transferring data from html form to Node js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send data from html page to NodeJS server .

my html code is :

```
<body>

        <nav>
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="button add">Add Product</a>
  <div class="dialog" style="display:none">
  <div class="title">Add Product</div>
  <form action="addevent" method="get">
    <input id = "name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Product Name"/>
    <input name="code" type="text" placeholder="Product Code"/>
    <input name="category" type="text" placeholder=" Category"/>
    <input name="brand" type="text" placeholder="Brand"/>
<input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
  </form>
</div>
</li>
<li class="radio">
  <a href="#" class="button active"></a>

  <a href="#" class="button"></a>

  <a href="#" class="button"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>        
</nav>
<p></p>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>




  </body>
```

and my server code is :

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
    port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 4004,
    publicDir = process.argv[2] || __dirname + '/public';
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');

//Show homepage
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/index.html");
});
app.get("/addevent", function (req, res){
   res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');

});

//Search page
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
app.use(errorHandler({
  dumpExceptions: true,
  showStack: true
}));

console.log("Server showing %s listening at http://%s:%s", publicDir, hostname, port);
app.listen(port);
```

but it gives following error when i submit the form from html page !

> ```
> Connect
> 500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>    at app.use.bodyParser.urlencoded.extended (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/server.js:17:45)
>    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>    at next (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>    at Route.dispatch (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>    at /home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
>    at Function.process_params (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
>    at next (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
>    at expressInit (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:33:5)
>    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/shubham/Music/pricesync/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> ```

Comment: In this line `req.body.name` (server.js), `req.body` is null or undefined

Comment: @JSantosh req.body is undefine

Comment: You cannot access a property of something that is undefined.so use console to log what you are actually getting in `req`

Comment: i am getting undefine when i am trying Console.log(req.body)

Answer (score 1):

In a GET HTTP request there is no `req.body` that's why the undefined error. The values of the form fields will be passed as query string hence you need to read query string values from the `req` object.

Comment: If i will do method POST instead of GET then it gives message : Cannot POST /addevent

Comment: If you do post then you need to change node code as well - `app.post('/addevent' .... )` Right now the the url addevent only support get request

Comment: Have you changes both the HTML and node code to use POST?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the routes below the middleware, and using the 'POST' http verb.

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
    port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 4004,
    publicDir = process.argv[2] || __dirname + '/public';
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs = require('fs');

//Search page
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(publicDir));

//Show homepage
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/index.html");
});

app.post("/addevent", function (req, res){
   res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
});

app.use(errorHandler({
  dumpExceptions: true,
  showStack: true
}));

console.log("Server showing %s listening at http://%s:%s", publicDir, hostname, port);
app.listen(port);
```

Make sure to change the form method to "post", as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data from an HTML form to server, best practice is to use POST method. Default encoding for form submission is:

**Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

In Express, you have used bodyParser middleware with json() method which does not work as the data you send is not JSON encoded.

You bodyParser needs to be before your route like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlEncoded());
app.post("/addevent", function (req, res){
....
```

I recommend that you read beginners book

- http://codecondo.com/5-free-beginner-friendly-books-learning-node-js/